# Select from a DataFrame based on several levels of the MultiIndex

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, multi-index

How to extend the logic of selecting from a DataFrame based on the first N-1 levels when N > 2?

As an example, consider a DataFrame:

```
midx = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([[0, 1], [10, 20, 30], ["a", "b"]])
df = pd.DataFrame(1, columns=midx, index=np.arange(3))
In[11]: df
Out[11]: 
   0                 1               
  10    20    30    10    20    30   
   a  b  a  b  a  b  a  b  a  b  a  b
0  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1
1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1
2  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1
```

Here, it is easy to select columns where 0 or 1 are in the first level:

```
df[[0, 1]]
```

But the same logic does not extend to selecting columns with 0 or 1 in the first and 10 or 20 in the second level:

```
In[13]: df[[(0, 10), (0, 20), (1, 10), (1, 20)]]
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (4,2) (3,) (4,2)
```

The following works:

```
df.loc[:, pd.IndexSlice[[0, 1], [10, 20], :]]
```

but is cumbersome, especially when the selector needs to be extracted from another DataFrame with a 2-level MultiIndex:

```
idx = df.columns.droplevel(2)
In[16]: idx
Out[16]: 
MultiIndex(levels=[[0, 1], [10, 20, 30]],
           labels=[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, ... 1, 2, 2]])
In[17]: df[idx]
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (12,2) (3,) (12,2)
```

**EDIT:** Ideally, I would also like to be able to order columns this way, not just select them — again, in the spirit of `df[[1, 0]]` being able to order columns based on the first level.

Answer (score 0):

If possible, you can filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with [`get_level_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.get_level_values.html) and [`isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.isin.html):

```
m1 = df.columns.get_level_values(0).isin([0,1])
m2 = df.columns.get_level_values(1).isin([10,20])

print (m1)
[ True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True]
print (m2)
[ True  True  True  True False False  True  True  True  True False False]
print (m1 & m2)
[ True  True  True  True False False  True  True  True  True False False]

df1 = df.loc[:, m1 & m2]
print (df1)
   0           1         
  10    20    10    20   
   a  b  a  b  a  b  a  b
0  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1
1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1
2  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1
```

---

```
df.columns = df.columns.droplevel(2)
print (df)
   0                 1               
  10 10 20 20 30 30 10 10 20 20 30 30
0  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1
1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1
2  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1

df2 = df.loc[:, m1 & m2]
print (df2)
   0           1         
  10 10 20 20 10 10 20 20
0  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1
1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1
2  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1
```

Comment: Thank you, perfectly acceptable. However, two problems: 1) this is barely less cumbersome than pd.IndexSlice that I have proposed; 2) this cannot order columns, only select them.

Comment: @IgorPozdeev - ya, what you need is not easy, nedd custom function with automcomplete `:` for each level which is necessary select all rows. And it is not easy :(